# What is a CCM_POST HTTP Request?

Tags: http, http-headers

I keep getting error messages like these on a server running an installation of an embedded Mongoose webserver

```
[1280931978] [error] [client 66.65.74.105] CCM_POST /ccm_system/request: Error 400: Bad Request
[1280931558] [error] [client 71.162.141.214] CCM_POST /ccm_system/request: Error 400: Bad Request
```

I figured out that *CCM_POST* seems to be some kind of HTTP command LIKE *GET*, *POST*, *PUT* and *DELETE*, but what is it supposed to do?

Is that some kind of vulnerability scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather confused Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager Client is trying to connect to it's site server, which it thinks your web server is.